# nginx order of server_name rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm playing around with nginx rewrite rules using `server` and `server_name`. The [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) sounds simple and clear enough about the order of precedence, but I'm getting some slightly odd behaviour and want to check whether I missed anything.

I am trying to redirect anything other than `www.domain.com` (e.g. `www.domain.net`, `www.domain.info`) to `www.domain.com`. With the exception of `www.domain.de` to redirecto to `www.domain.com/de`.

I have the following rules:

```
server {
   server_name domain.de www.domain.de;
   rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com/de$1 permanent;
}

server {
   server_name _;
   rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name localhost domain.com www.domain.com;
   ...
}
```

However, it seems like with this ruleset, it will always redirect *all* non `.com` domains to `www.domain.com/de`. Whereas if I flip the first two `server` segments it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the order of the rules important if the server names are explicitly specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right configuration would be:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name domain.de www.domain.de;
   return 301 http://www.domain.com/de$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;
   return 301 http://www.domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name "" localhost domain.com www.domain.com;
   ...
}
```

`server_name _;` is just a popular stub. The default value of the server_name directive is "" which handles requests without "Host" header. If client doesn't send it at all then `server_name ""` will leads to redirection loop in a configuration like yours.

Please, take a look at:

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info and links. Things are much clearer now and using `return 301` seems more appropriate than using rewrite!

Answer (score 2):

Using `server_name _;` to mean 'this is the default server' is a common mistake.  It has no special meaning, and you need to use the `default_server` flag on the listen directive to mark that second server as default:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Got a little confused with the docs [on this page](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) "the first server block with a matching listen directive (or implicit listen 80;)", so assumed the default would be the server with `listen 80` specified... Good answer, and I wish I can accept both, but VBart gave a slightly more detailed one, so I had to accept his.